# Check the type of generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a little problem with checking the type of a generic.

Lets assume you have a list like this:

```
public class List<T>
{

}
```

In there you would like to check what type the T is, so you go like this:

```
private void CheckType()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(CustomItem))
    {

    }
}
```

Now I am facing the problem with classes that have a common interface and I like to check if generic is the interface so for example:

```
public interface ICustomItem
{

}

public class CustomItemA : ICustomItem
{

}

public class CustomItemB : ICustomItem
{

}
```

Now I would like to have the type check work for both classes and just with the interface:

```
private void CheckType()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomItem))
    {

    }
}
```

This obviously fails, since the type isnt ICustomItem, but either CustomItemA, or CustomItemB.
Already found a method that gets a Interface but I don't assume thats the right way to do it:

```
private void CheckType()
{
    if (typeof(T).GetInterface("ICustomItem") != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Hope you can help me out.

Ps.: No I dont want to create a instance of T and just use the **is** operator.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail of what you're trying to achieve?  I suspect that your approach might be wrong as there are rarely good reasons to check types of generics...kind of stops them being generic.

Comment: How about using partial template specialization for statically resolving the type?

Comment: DoctorMick is right; the fact that you're asking this question indicates that you are probably abusing generics. The whole point of generics is that they are **generic**, that you don't care what the type is. If you're asking "how do I check the type of a generic?" then you are making a decision based on the type and your code is no longer *generic*.

Comment: @user2820379: What is "partial template specialization"?  C# doesn't have templates.

Comment: Ooops. I thought it was about c++.

Comment: @DoctorMick I have a generic list that does work for all classes, but there is one "special" class where I want to change only some part of the implementation, for me it seems easier to check the type instead of creating another class inheriting the generic class with a fixed type, but maybe during development I will change it.

Comment: @EricLippert see my comment to DoctorMick.

Comment: I'd create a separate class for the special case personally, it'd be cleaner and much more explicit for anyone who has to maintain the code in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (typeof(ICustomItem).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is `IsAssignableFrom()`...

```
if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICustomItem))) { }
```

You can also do this, which is basically the same as what you found except without the string comparison...

```
if (typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICustomItem))) { }
```

Comment: Note that these two things are different. `class C : IEnumerable<string>` is assignable to `IEnumerable<object>` but `IEnumerable<object>` is not on the interfaces list of `C`.

Comment: @EricLippert That's true, but since the OP's interface doesn't appear to involve generics, both should work. Good to keep this "gotcha" of generics in mind though.